# Filter object base on parameters - Check if Object values are equal to parameters ES6

Tags: arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I'm having a problem with object filter.

What I want to do is to filter array of objects when given parameters are equal to Object values.
And return the objects only if all values in the object are equal to these parameters.

```
let payload = {
   product: 'product1', 
   author = {
      id: 12,
      name = 'author1'
    }
}

Array I want to filter based on above parameters:
let data = [
    {
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 12, name: 'author1'}
    },
    {
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 20, name: 'author2'}
    },
     {
        product: 'product3,
        author: { id: 12, name: 'author1'}
    },
]
```

In this example as one param: product1 another one id author {id: 12, name: 'author1'} Then there is only one object matching:

```
let result = [{
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 12, name: 'author1'}
    }]
```

My approach is:

```
let keys = Object.keys(paylaod)

let matched
keys.forEach(key => {
    matched = data.filter(item => item[key] == payload[key])
})
```

What I'm getting is:

```
matched= [
    {
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 12, name: 'author1'}
    },
    {
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 20, name: 'author2'}
    },
]
```

I need to modify my filter function to get a result:

```
matched = [{
        product: 'product1,
        author: { id: 12, name: 'author1'}
    }]
```

Is there any way to filter object if has all given parameters ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your 'author' key points to an object, you won't be able to use the == operator to establish equality. Comparing objects in JS using == will only return true if they are the exact same object, not if they have the same contents. (Think identical twins. They look exactly the same but they are not the same person)

You're going to want to check for deep equality. [Here's a good link that explains it better than I can](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/)

**Option #1:** Implement your own deep equals filter function that will recursively check any child objects for equality as well.

```
function deepEqual(object1, object2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const key of keys1) {
    const val1 = object1[key];
    const val2 = object2[key];
    const areObjects = isObject(val1) && isObject(val2);
    if (
      areObjects && !deepEqual(val1, val2) ||
      !areObjects && val1 !== val2
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

**Option #2:** JSON.stringify

String comparison is easy! We can use the == operator for that!
If you call JSON.stringify(payload), it will return a stringified version of your object for comparison

```
JSON.stringify(payload) === JSON.stringify(item)
```

There IS an issue with this, however! JS Object Keys are not guaranteed to be in a specific order. If two objects have their keys in a different order, the JSON.stringify method will incorrectly return that they aren't equal. The following objects ARE equal but would be seen as NOT equal using this method

```
  let payload1 = {
       product: 'product1', 
       author = {
          id: 12,
          name = 'author1'
        }
    }

  let payload2 = {
       author = {
          id: 12,
          name = 'author1'
        }
       product: 'product1', 
    }


JSON.stringify(payload1) === JSON.stringify(payload2) //RETURNS FALSE
```

If you can guarantee the order of keys, this is a valid way of doing comparison!

**Option #3:**
Install a 3rd party library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) that will handle deep comparison for you. The function Lodash.isEqual(payload,item) should do the trick!

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer. I did deep check equality and it's working great!